# dd: unknown operand

Tags: partitioning

```
sudo dd if=/Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs-1m
```

I'm now getting this after I enter all of that

```
dd: unknown operand HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Answer (score 8):

Your input file name contains a space character so you need to use quotes. And it has to be `bs=1m` instead of `bs-1m`:

```
sudo dd if='/Macintosh HD/Users/nickzieno/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.img' of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```